# STRING_AGG except specific string from another column

Tags: sql

I wanna know how to exclude specific string in STRING_AGG? Here's my original query I want to exclude from the concatenation for a specific value on column name PRIMARY. Sorry I don't know how to use correct format, I will attach image instead for clear picture of my scenario. [image]

SELECT
t1.ID,
t1.NAME,
STRING_AGG(Trim(t2.COUNTRY), ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY COUNTRY) COUNTRY,
PRIMARY
FROM
t1
LEFT JOIN
t2
on
t1.ID=t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID,t1.NAME,t1.PRIMARY

t1

ID NAME PRIMARY
1 WHITE       US
2 RED        CA
3 BLUE       US
4 GREEN      GB

t2
ID  COUNTRY
1   US
1   CA
2   GB
2   DE
3   DE
3   CA
4   CA
4   DE
4   US

RESULT:
ID NAME       PRIMARY    COUNTRY
1 WHITE       US         CA      (EXCEPT US BECAUSE IT'S ALREADY IN PRIMARY)
2 RED         CA         GB;DE
3 BLUE        US         DE;CA
4 GREEN       DE         CA;DE;US (EXCEPT DE BECAUSE IT'S ALREADY IN PRIMARY)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `case` expression:

```
STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN t2.Country <> Primary THEN Trim(t2.COUNTRY) END, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COUNTRY)
```

`STRING_AGG()` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, unfortunately, we had to downgrade our MS SQL Server to V2016 it seems that STRING_AGG does not work with V2016. Here's the error message I got "STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name", is there any equivalent function in 2016?

Comment: @ThirdyLeon . . . This answers the question asked here, so you should accept it.  Then you can use the `for xml` method on earlier versions.  There should be plenty of examples on the web (google "string aggregation sql server").  If not, ask another question.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, I've just asked a new question. Thank you.